# Cloud Firestore concurrent connection limit for mobile per database and Maximum writes per second per database

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Firebase Cloud Firestore is officially out of beta. What is the new max concurrent connection limit for mobile per database and Maximum writes per second per database?

Release article 
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/announcing-cloud-firestore-general-availability-and-updates

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/01/cloud-firestore-in-general-availability.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current usage and limits are [always documented here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas).

Max concurrent connections: 1,000,000

Max writes per second: 10,000 (up to 10 MiB per second)

Comment: Was hoping it will go higher after beta haha. Hypothetically what will happen if there is sudden of 20k write in one sec

Comment: Error on write probably?

Comment: @DougStevenson If I connected to Firestore from a server connecting 100 users,woud that count as a single connection and therefore could I have 100 million concurrent connections?

Comment: @DougStevenson can you confirm my Feb 2023 Update answer?

Answer (score 0):

**Feb 2023 Update:**

As of now, there are **no longer** any mentions of limits on concurrent connections, nor writes per second on the [Firestore Usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) page (other than "Soft Limits"). I am cautiously optimistic that means these are no longer limiting factors?

Can someone from the Firestore team confirm?

Answer (score 0):

According to firebase blog https://firebase.blog/posts/2022/12/introducing-firestore-count-ttl-scale (December 8, 2022):

**Removing hard limits**

Now Firestore has fewer scaling limits than ever.

- No maximum reads per second.
- No maximum writes per second.
- No maximum concurrent, real-time, connections.